# <script> tags changes and locks font size - html, css, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

When I put a script in my html file, the font changes to default and no styling can be applied:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="topnav">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
    function myFunction() { 
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file looks like this:

```
ul.topnav li a {
    font-size: 20;      
}
```

If I take out the script the font size changes to 20.

Why does this happen?

Comment: shouldn't `<script>` be in the `<head>` and not the `<body>`?

Comment: `20` what? Meters? You forgot to put in a unit for your font size. And a script element should not affect rendering like that - did you copy and paste the *exact* code you're using? Which browser does this happen on?

Comment: It is the exact same code. However, putting in a unit fixed it. Thanks

Comment: @prideHURTS: I'm still curious. Which browser did this happen on?

Comment: Bizarre. I'll have to see if I can reproduce this and figure out what it means. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set 'px'.

Change to:

```
ul.topnav li a {
    font-size: 20px;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your font-size doesn't have a measurement.

```
font-size: 20;
```

Please try giving this an 'em' or 'px' and tell us the results.

```
ul.topnav li a {
    font-size: 20px;      
}
```